# Group multiple worksheets under one sheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there a way to group multiple worksheets under one worksheet. I do not want to select and work on them together. Just a visual way by which they can have some sort of hierarchy.

For example, I have three servers, A, B and C. I have cpu, host and IO information for all three and additionally heap information for server A. I have all these informations in separate CSVs. So now can I create one xlsx file which will have 3 worksheets Server A, Server B and Server C. And under each worksheet, separate worksheet for cpu, disk, IO and heap? It can look something like below pics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using MS Office 2016 Home.

Comment: How about adding colors for different groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

An Excel workbook contains one collection of worksheets. You cannot nest one worksheet inside/under another worksheet.